how to declare partitions by column like Hive
The Table Partitioning Guide doesn't say anything about this:  how to do the simplest thing? To declare something like PARTITION BY (x) and automatically each value is understood as a partition.

Seems ugly because need to redo CREATE TABLE new_table_name FOR VALUES IN ($val). With Hive is automatic, not need to create "by hand each partition"... Is there any automatic way in PostgreSQL?

you can use pg_partman for automatically run partition maintenance which is, for your case, creating new partitions automatically.
